# C# Dynamics Nav WebService unable to get authorization

Tags: c#, web-services, soap-client, navision

Im developing a project that calls multiple methods of web services from Dynamics Nav. It uses a SOAP request and sends an response xml to do the call.

I'm unable to authenticate to the web service as I get the following response:

> - response    {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>     {
>     Date: Thu, 31 Aug 2017 08:12:15 GMT
>     Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>     WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
>     Content-Length: 0
>     }}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

My sample of credentials code is:

```
var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usuarioText + ":" + passText);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
    AuthenticationHeaderValue("Windows", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));
```

I need windows authentication for calling the nav service, I think I'm doing something wrong sending the credentials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Service Tier is configured to use Windows Authentication, there are two ways to Authentication against Dynamics NAV Web Service.

Using your current Credentials:

```
// Creates instance of service and sets credentials.
Customer_Service service = new Customer_Service();
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Or setting Credentials (e.g. from Config):

```
// Creates instance of service and sets credentials.
Customer_Service service = new Customer_Service();
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

More at MSDN: [Walkthrough: Registering and Using a Page Web Service (SOAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355316(v=nav.90).aspx)